# Qt with boost::bimap<QUuid, QString>

Tags: qt, c++11, boost

Does anyone has ideas, why destructing the boost::bimap takes very long time?
My code:

```
typedef boost::bimaps::bimap<QUuid, QString> bimap;
bimap mapper;
int nEvents = 1000000;

QSet<QString> names;
QSet<QUuid> ids;
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nEvents; ++i)
    {
        const QString name = QUuid::createUuid().toString();
        const QUuid id = QUuid::createUuid();

        mapper.insert({id, name});
    }
}
```

From the profile of the code I see, that destructing of `bimap` takes several minutes. I'm quite confused with this...

Comment: Do you measure the performance in debug or release mode?

Comment: @vahancho in both modes.

Comment: I notice the same effect with the ordinary `std::map<QUuid, QString>` - destruction takes pretty much time (minutes). However, for real performance measurement you have to try to run your application detached from debugger. Invoke Ctrl+F5 instead of just F5, if you use Visual Studio. In my case insertion of takes ~4sec., map destruction takes 0.7sec.

Comment: @vahancho, yes, you are right. The time really depends on detaching from debugger even if you build in release mode. I use QtCreator. But anyway it works fine now. Thanks!